# Android talking to PHP

Tags: php, android

I am new to Android and am currently trying to connect Android to a database through PHP. I can easily connect the PHP script to my database but I cannot get Android to talk to the PHP script. I have tried multiple examples - http://www.androidaspect.com/2013/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php.html - but cannot seem to get it to work. If I could get Android to simply receive a message saying 'hello' from the PHP script, I would easily be able to finish my work but I cannot. I have been told to do things such as use ASync but quite frankly that just makes this so much more complicated. Any help would be appreciated in getting my Android side to talk to my PHP side. Thank you very much in advance.

I've deleted the actual code that I've tried but one tutorial is linked above and the other had me try this -

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rec","mar"));
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/select.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
is = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
   sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
result = sb.toString();
JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
name=(json_data.getString("name"));
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Name : "+name,
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: can code u have tried can u post here?

Comment: -- Mistake, editing above.

Comment: for some time now (in API versions >= Honeycomb) you have been required to do networking on a separate thread, else you get a NetworkOnMainThreadException. (Google for it) Whoever wrote that tutorial is an idiot for not realising that in 2013, don't base your code on that. Find examples of HttpClient in an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below class as inner class and change url and parameters :

```
class PlaceOrder extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httpPst = new HttpPost(

                "yout_url");

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(

                2);

                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "apple"));

                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pw", "apple"));

                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",
                        "apple@gmail.com"));

                parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "apple"));

                httpPst.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

                HttpResponse httpRes = httpClient.execute(httpPst);

                String str = convertStreamToString(
                        httpRes.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

                Log.i("mlog", "outfromurl" + str);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;

        }

    }

    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        try {

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                is.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        return sb.toString();

    }
```

use http://json.parser.online.fr/ for validating json

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to use RETROFIT:

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Simply read a bit in the introduction.

Its optimized for Android, so that the Response Callbacks will be executed on the MainThread, so that you can manipulate UI controls.

**Example:**

```
public interface TimetrackingService {

    @GET("/projekte")
    void getProjects(Callback<List<Project>> cb);

    @POST("/timetrack")
    void submit(
            @Query("projektId") int projektId, 
            @Query("start") String start, 
            @Query("ende") String ende, 
            Callback<Void> cb);
}
public class Project {

    public int id;
    public String name;

}
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(url)
    .build();
TimetrackingService service = restAdapter.create(TimetrackingService.class);


    service.getProjects(new Callback<List<Project>>() {

        @Override
        public void success(List<Project> list, Response response) {
            Log.d(LOG, "success");
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError e) {
            Log.d(LOG, "failure");
        }

    });
```